# In material progress bar, I want to add tracking or marker at some dynamic points like image

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

In material progress bar, I want to add tracking or marker  [image], instead of showing horizontal line, Is it possible to show progress bar along
with add slice

I am using this material progress bar

```html
<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" value="40"></mat-progress-bar>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Angular Material provides you fixed components.
If you need some customization then you need to tweak it's behavior or even add outer elements and wrap it all as a new element.

To your question: Yes it is possible.

Here is an example (not a good one but a sufficient one) for how to achieve it:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ma2ht6

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help!  Can we make it dynamically ? I didn't  want add tracker using css

Comment: It would be helpful to describe the fix and post a working sample.  The sample at stackblitz shows no indicators.